# Need help understanding alsa drivers

Tags: driver, alsa

I'm trying to debug the sound system on a amlogic device.  amixer and alsamixer aren't working as expected and amixer can crash the system.  What I'm struggling with is that the drivers pass methods for accessing the hardware registers by constructing a snd_kcontrol object all as described in Writing an ALSA Driver on the ALSA website.  But amixer cset calls snd_ctl_elem_write from control.c which refers to element_write in a snd_ctl_t object.

I can't see any link between the defined snd_kcontrol and any snd_ctl_t objects so can't see how amixer is supposed to be writing to the hardware.  How is it normally done?

Comment: That link is established by `cnd_ctl_add()`.

Comment: Thanks but afaict snd_ctl_add() only takes a snd_card and snd_kcontrol struct. Nothing to do with snd_ctl_t.  Sorry if I'm being thick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In user space, a control device is represented by `snd_ctl_t`, which contains the file handle of the device node. `element_write` points to `snd_ctl_hw_elem_write()`, which issues a system call.

In the kernel, an opened device file is represented by a `struct snd_ctl_file`, which is linked to the `struct snd_card`.

Comment: Thanks again.  What confused me is that there is just one snd_ctl_t per card whereas there can be many snd_kcontrols, so they are really separate entities and different routes into the registers.